# Accessing the content of a enum with an owned pointer in a for loop

Tags: rust

For the code:

```
enum A {
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Baz(~str)
}

#[test]
fn test_vector(){
    let test_vec = ~[Foo, Bar, Baz(~"asdf")];

    for x in test_vec.iter() {
        match x {
            &Foo   => true,
            &Bar   => true,
            &Baz(x) => x == ~"asdf"
        };
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
stackoverflow.rs:15:13: 15:19 error: cannot move out of dereference of & pointer
stackoverflow.rs:15             &Baz(x) => x == ~"asdf"
                             ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

If I change the string to an int it compiles fine.

My questions is: How do I access the contents of an owned pointer in an enum in a for loop? Is there an alternate iterator I should be using?

The version of Rust i'm using is compiled from master.

Comment: I'm not near my computer, and 0.7 fails to install on this laptop, but I think you should try `&Baz(ref x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in match cases are moved by default. You are not allowed to move `x`, because everything in loop is immutable. To get a reference to `x` str you need to use `ref` keyword:

```
&Baz(ref x) => *x == ~"asdf"
```

Comment: Note that `"asdf" == *x` or `x.as_slice() == "asdf"` will be more efficient, since they don't have the allocation. (The fact that it isn't possible to just write `*x == "asdf"` is regarded as a bug.)